# get node index in VM extensions in Azure VM Scale Sets

Tags: azure

In a Azure Resource Manager Template for Azure VM Scale Set one can configure vm extensions using the extensionProfile property.

```
 "extensionProfile": {
                "extensions": [
                 {
            "name": "DockerExtension",
            "properties": {
              "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
              "type": "DockerExtension",
              "typeHandlerVersion": "1.0",
              "settings": {
                "compose": {
                  "consul": {
                    "image": "progrium/consul",
                    "command": "[concat('-server -node master', copyIndex(), ' ', variables('consulServerArgs')[copyIndex()])]"                       
                  },

                }
              }
            }
          }
                ]    
    }
```

Are there any template functions that allows one to get the resourceid or the node number of the node that the extension is applied for? Similar as if one was doing a manually loop and using the copyIndex() function?

Basicly, i need to get the local ip address of the node in the command of the docker extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a resource loop type construct for extensions to apply differently to different VMs within a VM scale set resource.

Could you add a load balancer to the scale set and define NAT rules which map IPAddr:frontendport+x to VMSS/VMx:backendport?

A node can get its own IP address, so is there any workaround you could make in a script running on the node, or in node reporting their IP address to a location that can be then picked up by master nodes?

Comment: I am exploring options of installing the docker extension using rest API to the vmscale set vms after deployment atm. I am able to get the list of vms in the scaleset using the rest API, and also their network interfaces, just need to figure out if vmscaleset vms have the same rest api as normal vms when wanting to add the extension.

Comment: the /*vmss*/name/vms*/isntanceid/extensions/ didnt work for scalesets.  Going to experiment abit with a custom scripts.

Comment: You can deploy an extension to a VM Scale Set after it has been deployed, and it applies to all the VMs in the scale set, with the same configuration. However, you can't deploy an extension to individual VMs in the scale set, with different per-VM settings, either during or after VMSS deployment.

Comment: i didnt find anyhting related to extensions in the api, https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt589023.aspx. You mean I can do it with the ARM templates right?

Comment: Correct. There's nothing in the API specific to extensions. It's a case of doing a PUT or a PATCH on a deployment, which includes extension properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reference keyword of the ARM template.

It would look something like:

```
[reference(variables('nicName')).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress]
```

See this template for an example usage: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/26ff381b86865dc8583a4bc1a437ebffcc2617fd/memcached-multi-vm-ubuntu/azuredeploy.json

Comment: The problem is that the nic is created as part of the VM scale set and do not have a reference directly? are you sure that your example works with azure VM scale sets?

Comment: The syntax may not be exact, but should be similar. The key thing is that you're using the reference keyword. Also the docker extension should be dependent on the VM scale set. If you're having problems, use resources.azure.com to find the exact property you're looking for on your resource.

Comment: Sorry, your wrong. Just got confirmed from vm scaleset team that its not possible to get the reference to the nic of the vm inside the vmscaleset extensionProfile.